# Do Loop Until Black Cell

Tags: vba, loops, do-loops

I am almost there! But having trouble figuring out out to loop a portion of my code. See "loop portion" towards the bottom

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, x As Integer, ws As Worksheet


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Brand By Vendor "

    Sheets("Brand By Vendor ").Range("A1") = "STORE"
    Sheets("Brand By Vendor ").Range("B1") = "BRAND CODE"
    Sheets("Brand By Vendor ").Range("C1") = "BRAND NAME"
    
Set sh3 = Sheets("Brand By Vendor ")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    sh3.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
sh2.Range("A2").Copy
    sh3.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, operation:=xlNone, skipblanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    sh3.Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
sh2.Activate
Range("A2").Select

'loop portion

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    sh3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
sh2.Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Copy
    sh3.Activate
    sh3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":A" & lastrow)
       
       
End Sub
```

I want the loop portion to execute until the there is a blank cell in sh2 in Column A. Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Should the post title say  "Do Loop Until Blank Cell"? The description says Blank and the title Black. If Blank, set the range that you will like to loop through `Sheet2.Range("A:A")` for instance. Define your conditional, in your case you could use `IsEMpty()` and then do your stuff:

**Illustrative:**

```
Dim loopRange As Range
Dim c As Range

Set loopRange = Sheet2.Range("A:A")

For Each c In loopRange 

    If IsEmpty(c) = False Then

      '[Your code block to do stuff within the loop goes here]

    End If
Next c
```

Is recomendable to shorten the range not to loop through all the cells in column A.

**Using your code:**

```
Dim sh2LoopRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim Sh2LastRow as long

'Find the last row in sheet 2 colum A with content
sh2Lastrow = sh2.Range("A" & sh2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Define the range to run the loop through
Set sh2LoopRange = sh2.Range("A1:A" & sh2Lastrow)

'Iterate through the range
For Each c In sh2LoopRange

'If c is not empty it will do stuff
    If IsEmpty(c) = False Then

       '[Your code block to do stuff within the loop goes here]

    End If
Next c
```